# PGP encryption in Linux

Tags: linux, pgp

How should I encrypt a file using `gpg` linux command with PGP public key?

I have searched on google and I found this command

```
gpg --output doc.gpg --encrypt --recipient blake@cyb.org doc
```

but I didn't find where to keep the public key in the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as you said, you already have a key file, then you need to `gpg --import` that key into your keyring.

After that, you can `gpg --list-keys` to see the email address that you have to use as the argument to `--recipient`.

Answer (score 0):

You have already specified it using `--recipient` option. Please check manual page or try `gpg --help`.

Comment: I don't want --recipient option. I wan't the file to encrypt using pgp public key.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: `gpg --encrypt --recipient someone@something.com secret.txt` will encrypt file `secret.txt` using public key `someone@something.com` and produce `secret.txt.gpg`

Comment: I have no idea about the gpg command. So you mean "someone@something.com" is public key but here I don't have any such user as public key. I have a file with pgp public key which will be similar like 
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
***************************
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

Comment: Okay. Now I get you. I thought that you have imported the key using `gpg`. Use `gpg --import new.gpg` where `new.gpg ` is public key file. Once this is done verify it with `gpg --list-keys`.